How to display on canvas ts tauri reacts to a PDF page so that each element of the page (text, graphics, images) is displayed as in the original?
I want to make a PDF editor. But I don’t have much experience. Please help me. First, I want to display the contents of the page correctly. So that everything is like in the original. Then I’ll think about editing.
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { readBinaryFile } from "@tauri-apps/api/fs";
import { open } from "@tauri-apps/api/dialog";
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "/pdfjs/pdf.worker.min.js";

interface TextItem {
  str: string;
  dir: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  transform: number[];
  fontName: string;
  fontSize: number;
  color: string;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  hasEOL: boolean;
}

interface ImageItem {
  dataUrl: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  rotation: number;
  scaleX: number;
  scaleY: number;
}

interface GraphicsItem {
  type: string;
  opList: any;
  transform: number[];
  x: number;
  y: number;
  color: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  fillColor: string;
  strokeColor: string;
  lineWidth: number;
  dashArray: number[];
  dashPhase: number;
  miterLimit: number;
}

interface PageParams {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  scale: number;
}

interface PageData {
  textItems: TextItem[];
  imageItems: ImageItem[];
  graphicsItems: GraphicsItem[];
  pageParams: PageParams;
}

const PdfEditor = () => {
  const [pdfData, setPdfData] = useState<Uint8Array | null>(null);
  const [pageData, setPageData] = useState<PageData | null>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);

  const loadPdf = async () => {
    const filePath = await open({
      filters: [{ name: "PDF", extensions: ["pdf"] }],
    });

    if (filePath && typeof filePath === "string") {
      const data = await readBinaryFile(filePath);
      setPdfData(new Uint8Array(data));
    }
  };

  const renderPage = async () => {
    if (pdfData) {
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
      const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
      const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const context = canvas?.getContext("2d");

      if (canvas && context) {
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
        const operatorList = await page.getOperatorList();

        const textItems: TextItem[] = textContent.items.map((item: any) => {
          const fontName = item.fontName
            ? item.fontName.split("#")[1]
            : "unknown";
          return {
            str: item.str,
            dir: item.dir,
            width: item.width,
            height: item.height,
            transform: item.transform,
            fontName: fontName,
            fontSize: item.height,
            color: item.color || "black",
            x: item.transform[4],
            y: item.transform[5],
            hasEOL: item.hasEOL || false,
          };
        });

        const imageItems: ImageItem[] = await extractImages(page);

        const graphicsItems: GraphicsItem[] = operatorList.fnArray.map(
          (fn: any, index: number) => ({
            type: fn,
            opList: fn,
            transform: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][0]
              : [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            x: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][1]
              : 0,
            y: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][2]
              : 0,
            color: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][3]
              : "black",
            width: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][4]
              : 1,
            height: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][5]
              : 1,
            fillColor: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][6]
              : "transparent",
            strokeColor: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][7]
              : "black",
            lineWidth: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][8]
              : 1,
            dashArray: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? Array.isArray(operatorList.argsArray[index][9])
                ? operatorList.argsArray[index][9]
                : []
              : [],
            dashPhase: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][10]
              : 0,
            miterLimit: operatorList.argsArray[index]
              ? operatorList.argsArray[index][11]
              : 10,
          })
        );

        const pageParams: PageParams = {
          width: viewport.width,
          height: viewport.height,
          scale: 1,
        };

        setPageData({
          textItems,
          imageItems,
          graphicsItems,
          pageParams,
        });

        drawComponentsOnCanvas(context, {
          textItems,
          imageItems,
          graphicsItems,
          pageParams,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const extractImages = async (page: any): Promise<ImageItem[]> => {
    const opList = await page.getOperatorList();
    const imageItems: ImageItem[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < opList.fnArray.length; i++) {
      if (opList.fnArray[i] === pdfjsLib.OPS.paintImageXObject) {
        const imgIndex = opList.argsArray[i][0];
        const img = page.objs.get(imgIndex);

        const { width, height, imageMask, data } = img;
        if (!imageMask) {
          const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

          if (context) {
            const imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
            imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(data));

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

            const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            imageItems.push({
              dataUrl,
              width,
              height,
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              rotation: 0,
              scaleX: 1,
              scaleY: 1,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return imageItems;
  };

  const drawComponentsOnCanvas = (
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    data: PageData
  ) => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, data.pageParams.width, data.pageParams.height);

    console.log("Page Data:", data);

    data.textItems.forEach((item) => {
      context.font = `${item.fontSize}px ${item.fontName}`;
      context.fillStyle = item.color;
      context.fillText(item.str, item.x, item.y);
    });

    data.graphicsItems.forEach((item) => {
      context.save();
      if (item.transform.length === 6) {
        context.transform(
          item.transform[0],
          item.transform[1],
          item.transform[2],
          item.transform[3],
          item.transform[4],
          item.transform[5]
        );
      }
      context.strokeStyle = item.strokeColor;
      context.fillStyle = item.fillColor;
      context.lineWidth = item.lineWidth;
      context.setLineDash(item.dashArray);
      context.lineDashOffset = item.dashPhase;

      switch (item.type) {
        case "stroke":
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(item.x, item.y);
          context.lineTo(item.x + item.width, item.y + item.height);
          context.stroke();
          break;
        case "fill":
          context.beginPath();
          context.rect(item.x, item.y, item.width, item.height);
          context.fill();
          context.stroke();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      context.restore();
    });

    data.imageItems.forEach((item) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = item.dataUrl;
      img.onload = () => {
        context.drawImage(
          img,
          item.x,
          item.y,
          item.width * item.scaleX,
          item.height * item.scaleY
        );
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadPdf}>Load PDF</button>
      <button onClick={renderPage}>Render Page</button>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfEditor;

This code helped me implement ChatGPT. But no matter how I explained it to him, he didn’t give me a ready answer. I need to parse the page into its contents and convert everything into ordinary ts objects. So that in the future you can make react components based on them and display them on canvas. I have different buttons like a pencil, curved lines, squares, text and so on that are in regular editors. Then I want to listen to mouse events and perform manipulations with components and create new ones.

Thanks for the comment. Yes, you are right. I install security systems and often have to read projects. I have a visual impairment and it is very difficult for me to look at projects on site. I would like to somehow make my work easier. On a project, everything doesn’t always look clear to me. I have an idea to somehow edit, parse and process this format in text models of neural networks. I haven’t figured out exactly how yet. At the moment, my main goal with this idea is to draw each element on the canvas and then I don’t have to convert it back to PDF. Would really appreciate any help.

I also have a project in python https://github.com/anton84tiunov/python_pdf_parser/tree/master. there I achieved more success. I wrote it without ChatGpt.

still decided to return to python. maybe someone can help.

How can I use MuPDF-GL in a TypeScript project. If you can, explain how to install it and where is its documentation. I tried https://mupdfjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guide/node/typescript/index.html but I got an error.
